# Why is geometry default vmarginratio 2:3?

Tags: geometry

I have just noticed that the `geometry package` default ratio between top and bottom margins is 2:3 rather than 1:1 (i.e., `vmarginratio=2:3`). Can anybody explain what’s the reason for this choice of default values (if any)? Is it recommended to change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general the bottom margin is larger than the top margin. My *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) provides examples of over 30 page designs, the earliest dating from 1559, on pages 32 onwards. The 2:3 ration is reasonable.

You can of course change it but I suggest that as you have asked about the ratio you don't change it until you are more aware of the typographic history of page design. --- GOM